# jQuery UI Autocomplete -- make click/enter move to next field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have multiple input fields to autocomplete with jQuery UI's autocomplete plugin. Each input has a corresponding hidden input (user name vs. user id, for example). In the change handler, I'm setting the value of the hidden field. This works exactly as expected.

The trouble comes in when I want to make the Return key + mouse click automatically select the next field. If I don't manually trigger the change event, the change event's `ui.item` is null. If I do trigger it manually, it fires a second change event with a null `ui.item`.

I can add a guard in change to protect against a null `ui.item`, but this would prevent me from clearing fields I've previously filled in.

In short -- pressing tab, enter, or mouse clicking should set the text input's value to the user name, set the hidden input to the user id, and focus the next text input.

Here's a JSFiddle with inline comments to illustrate/explain the problem in context: http://jsfiddle.net/shipstar/Jvfx3/4/

Thanks!

Comment: Another approach is to use the autocomplete's original source array to find the relevant value. This is fine (although clumsy) for small data sets, but seems inadvisable for larger data.

Comment: Another hacky solution would be to add a blank entry and set minLength to 0. This is visually awkward, and will perform poorly when I switch to a server-side data source.

Answer (score 1):

Move the focus logic inside the [close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close), and your value updater inside the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select).

http://jsfiddle.net/Jvfx3/6/

```
select: function (event, ui){
    var $userIdField = $(this).siblings(".user-id");
    var userId = ui.item ? ui.item.userId : '';
    $userIdField.val(userId);

    $(this).siblings('label').find('span').text(userId);
},
close: function(event, ui){
    if (!event.keyCode || event.keyCode === 13){
        $(this).parents('form').find('.user-name').filter(function (){
            return $(this).val() === '';
        }).first().focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixes an inadvertent side-bug, but I think the core issue still stands -- two events are firing. I could setTimeout on the _trigger to ensure proper order, but that still feels like a hack.

Comment: re: fiddle #6 -- This fixes the double firing, but loses the ability to delete previously selected entries because the select event only fires when you explicitly select something in the source data. #whackamole

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your still having this problem or not, but I was having the exact same difficulties as you were. I am still practically a newbie when it comes to JS & jQuery, so there may be other better, cleaner ways to do this, but I don't know what they are, and I managed to get this to work in my code, so hopefully it works for you or anyone else with this problem.

I expanded on @Jacob_Kralls solution, and tried to solve the problem of being unable to delete a previously selected entry. Since ui.item returns null after setting the focus, I added a second hidden field to store a copy of the value selected, then rather than checking against large or remote data-sets, you can compare against the copied value field.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvfx3/11/

Html snippet with new checkVal field:

```
 <div>
  <input type="hidden" class="user-id" id="h1" />
  <input type="hidden" class="user-name-checkVal" id="cv1" />
  <input type="text"   class="user-name" id="t1" />
  <label>User ID is: <span>undefined</span></label>
 </div>
```

Javascript snippets:

In the select event, set the checkVal field equal to value selected.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).siblings(".user-id").val(ui.item.userId);
  $(this).siblings(".user-name-checkVal").val(ui.item.value);
  $(this).siblings('label').find('span').text(ui.item.userId);
},
```

in the change event compare username value to checkVal, allow empty username when value is deleted.

```
change: function (event, ui) {
  var username = $(this).val();
  var checkVal = $(this).siblings(".user-name-checkVal").val();
  if (username == '') {
     //username has changed, and now its null. value has been deleted.
     // clear everything set when value was selected.

     $(this).val('');
     $(this).siblings(".user-name-checkVal").val('');
     $(this).siblings(".user-id").val('undefined');
     $(this).siblings('label').find('span').text('undefined');

   } else if (username != checkVal) {
     //username was not selected from list. reset everything set by select.
     $(this).siblings(".user-name-checkVal").val('');
     $(this).siblings(".user-id").val('');
     $(this).siblings('label').find('span').text('undefined');

     //user-name is invalid, alert user of the error.
     alert('Invalid username. choose from list.');

     //since the value was entered, and not selected, keep focus here.
     $(this).val('');
     $(this).focus();
   }
},
```

on the close event, again compare username and checkVal, only set focus to next item in list if they match. (this worked in chrome, but in firefox, cursor still ended up in next item, no idea why)

```
 close: function (event, ui) {
    if (!event.keyCode || event.keyCode === 13) {
       var username = $(this).val();
       var checkVal = $(this).siblings(".user-name-checkVal").val();
       if (username == checkVal) {
          $(this).parents('form').find('.user-name')
                 .filter(function () { return $(this).val() === ''; })
                 .first().focus();
        }

     }
}
```